# How did I receive the two reputation points?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, reputation, migration

I had asked a question on Linguistics Stack Exchange site and a user answered it. I accepted the answer on that site.

The question migrated to this site just recently, because it can fit better here and it may receive more answers.

I had a reputation of 101 on this site (thanks to the trust reputation) prior to the migration. The question has received one up-vote so far (it didn't receive any up-votes prior to the migration), so my reputation should've became 111 here. But my reputation is **113** right now. The only reason I can think about is that I've received the 2 reputations because the answer on the question is accepted. But as I said before the acceptance took place before the migration process. So how did I receive the 2 reputation points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [your reputation history in your profile](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/9103/snack-exchange?tab=reputation).
It contains a detailed list of most (and in your case all) reputation changes with short descriptions.
The only thing I know not to be shown is voting down someone else's answers; it costs 1 point and you get it back if the answer is deleted, and showing that in the reputation history would reduce the anonymity of your voting.

On this site you have three reputation events: +100 for association, +2 for acceptance, and +10 for an upvote.
Apparently the acceptance points are calculated to be consistent with the site your question ends up on.
[Your reputation history on the originating site](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/30313/snack-exchange?tab=reputation) shows no trace of that question anymore, so it appears that the reputation associated with this post was migrated with the post.
This seems to hold for the reputation from upvotes and acceptance as well, as [the reputation history of the user answering you](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/1196/janus-bahs-jacquet?tab=reputation) shows.

Answer (score 2):

To put it another way, reputation is calculated based on the current state of the database, with no knowledge of what's happened in the past. According to the database, you currently have a question on Latin.SE with one upvote and an accepted answer, therefore your reputation should be 113 (1, +100 association bonus, +10 upvote, +2 accepted answer).

That's also why you get reputation back if an answer you downvoted was deleted, but your profile won't explain why. As far as the rep database is concerned, it's as if that answer never existed, so you never lost the reputation for downvoting it in the first place.